# ES6 Modules are loaded Synchronously or Asynchronously?

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, ecmascript-6

Module loader is responsible for loading modules.

What I know is module loader loads modules in browser asynchronously whereas in Node.js it loads synchronously.

I wanted to confirm whether this information is correct or not.

Comment: What's the question? ES6 doesn't specify how modules should be loaded and supports both.

Comment: So, which specific module loader are you asking about? Notice that node doesn't have an ES6 module loader at all yet, so we can hardly tell you anything about it.

Comment: @Bergi: Now it has. So what's your answer?

Comment: @Rainning Dependencies declared with `import` statements are loaded before any code is evaluated, so whether loading is async or sync is not observable. Module evaluation [can be asynchronous](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#top-level-await); while evaluation of [commonjs modules](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#interoperability-with-commonjs) continues to work as it did before. And then there's [`import()` expressions](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#import-expressions) which have an asynchronous return value, but it's not stated whether they load files synchronously or not.

Comment: @Rainning I don't see how that comment is an answer to "*What's the benefit of using ES6 module syntax*"

Comment: @Rainning Oh, that. But no, the real benefit of ES6 modules is their declarative syntax, with better readability and tooling.

Answer (score 10):

ES6 module loaders will be asynchronous while node.js module loaders are not.

Here are some key aspects of module loaders:

> - Module code automatically runs in strict mode and there’s no way to opt-out of strict mode.
> - Variables created in the top level of a module are not automatically added to the shared global scope. They exist only within
>     the top-level scope of the module.
> - The value of `this` in the top level of a module is undefined. Does not allow HTML-style comments within the code (a leftover feature from
>     the early browser days).
> - Modules must export anything that should be available to code outside    of the module.

https://leanpub.com/understandinges6/read#leanpub-auto-modules

> Modules, in general, solve several problems for developers. First,
>   they allow the developer to separate code into smaller pieces, called
>   modules. Second, they make it easy for developers to load (inject)
>   those modules into other sections of code. Having modules injected
>   like this helps keep project code uncoupled from the module (read:
>   improved testability). **And third, modules can load scripts
>   asynchronously.** This means that apps can begin loading faster, as
>   they don’t require all scripts to be loaded prior to executing code.

http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001623/ch03.html#_default_values

On the other hand because `node.js` is based on `require` which is synchronous this means `node.js` does not provide an asynchronous variant out of the box.

Of course there are async module loaders for node ([async-require](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async-require)), but natively (with require) is not supported.

Comment: You have "buried the lead" to use an old newspaper phrase.  I'd suggest you take your last sentence and put it first.  I'm reading through your whole answer and thinking that you're not answer that actual question asked until the last sentence.  Generally good info in the answer, but I'd suggest you start with answering the question and then have the other info.

Comment: *"ES6 module loaders will be asynchronous"* This is wrong (or at least makes assumptions). ES6 doesn't specify how modules should be loaded. How modules defined with ES6 are loaded most likely depends on the environment the code runs. Also, given the way ES6 modules are defined, all dependencies must exist loaded before the module itself can execute, making it irrelevant how the dependencies have been loaded.

Comment: What about --experimental-modules? Then it is the same rt (assuming you use mjs).

Answer (score 0):

ESM is intentionally async (to accomodate loading over networks) and the rationale behind `import` also aims at knowing during code interpretation what dependencies exist (e.g. allowing bundlers to do treeshaking etc). This is also the reason to have imports at the beginning of your files and they can't be conditional (unless you use the `await import()` syntax).

You can also not `eval(readFileSync(moduleFile))` if you use ESM syntax in the loaded file.